# Access 2013: How to control what form changes get saved and which get cancelled

Tags: forms, ms-access-2013

I have a form with 3 buttons:

**Save** - which saves the form

**NewReport** - which becomes visible only after current form is saved and is supposed to clear the form and let the user input another form of data.

**Close** - which should close the application without saving the unfinished form.

I cannot seem to figure out how to control these functions using the Before Update event procedure.

One of the things that I do not understand is that the Save command doesn't actually wright the data to the table until I somehow change the focus of the form. So if my user is entering data and hits the Save button, at the completion of the save command, the table does not yet have the data saved. It only appears in the table after focus changes; like from a Requery.

Here is my code in its current version:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Cause As Variant

Private Sub btnClose_Click()

    Cause = "CloseButton"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmReports", acSaveNo

End Sub

Private Sub btnNewReport_Click()

    Cause = "NewReport"
    Me.Requery
    Me.RepStatus = ""

End Sub

Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

    Dim outl As Outlook.Application
    Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem

    'blnGood = True
    Cause = "SaveButton"

    'Save the Record
    DoCmd.Save acForm, "frmReports"

'    If Me.DateOfVisit <> "" Then
        Me.RepStatus = "Report Saved!"
'        Set outl = New Outlook.Application
'        Set mi = outl.CreateItem(olMailItem)
'            mi.Body = "A new report was just recorded."
'            mi.Subject = Application.CurrentUser & " Just Logged a Report."
'            mi.To = "rich.temen@cox.net"
'            mi.Send
'
'        Set mi = Nothing
'        Set outl = Nothing
'    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strMsg As String

    Select Case Cause
        Case "SaveButton"
            Me.btnNewReport.Visible = True
            'do nothing

        Case "NewReport"
            'di this

        Case "CloseButton"
            Me.Undo

    End Select

    'If Not blnGood Then
     '   strMsg = "Please use the Save button to save your Report," & _
    '             vbNewLine & "or Escape to reset the form."
    '    Call MsgBox(Prompt:=strMsg, Title:="Before Update")
    'End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Me.btnNewReport.Visible = False
    Cause = ""

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help on this one, I have been going around in circles for hours.

Rich

Comment: What you need to know is that `DoCmd.Save acForm, "frmReports"` does not save the form's data (the record); it save's changes to the form's design. What you actually need to save the current record is `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`. Similarly, `DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmReports", acSaveNo` is telling Access not to save changes to the form's design as you close the form. It is **not** saying "don't save the record". If anything is doing that it's the `Me.Undo` in the BeforeUpdate event code.

Comment: Thanks, Skippy. I didn't realize that.  That helped a bunch.

Comment: No worries! Please feel free to give my previous comment an up-vote if it was useful. Thanks.